# boost serialization std::unique_ptr support

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-serialization

Does the boost serialization library support serialization of std::unique_ptr?
I tried to compile the code below, but if I include the 
**boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs); oa << g;** line,

the compiler (btw gcc4.7 with -std=c++11 flag) throws an error

**/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘class std::unique_ptr’ has no member named ‘serialize’**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
class MyDegrees
{
public:
  void setDeg(int d){deg = d;}
  int getDeg()const {return deg;}
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    { ar & deg; }
  int deg;
};
class gps_position
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    { ar & degrees; }
    std::unique_ptr<MyDegrees> degrees;
public:
    gps_position(): degrees(std::unique_ptr<MyDegrees>(new MyDegrees)){};
    void setDeg(int d){degrees->setDeg(d);}
    int getDeg() const {return degrees->getDeg();}
};
int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    gps_position g;
    g.setDeg(45);
    std::cout<<g.getDeg()<<std::endl;
    {// compiler error, fine if commented out
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs); oa << g;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Boost were you using?

Comment: @David I have no idea, it was long time ago. I had implemented the solution  which you can find below in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no out of the box adaption. You will need to provide a non-intrusive adapter yourself. See the [tutorial here](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/) to get an idea how to do that.

Comment: good starting point would be http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/example/demo_auto_ptr.cpp

Comment: This is an outdated answer, all std smart pointers are supported now.

Comment: @Kaaf Feel free to suggest an edit with the specific version in which this changed. Unfortunately I'm not a Boost (or even C++ user) anymore and find this hard to answer nowadays.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure how to interpret [this list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), but it seems like support for this was added sometime after 1.48. I am using 1.58 and it is included. Just

```
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
```

and then it will work as follows:

```
#include <memory>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>

#include <fstream>

class Point
{
public:
    Point() { }

    float x = 1.;
    float y = 2.;
    float z = 3.;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class TArchive>
    void serialize(TArchive & archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & x;
        archive & y;
        archive & z;
    }
};

void ValidUniquePointer()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Point> p(new Point());

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << p;
    outputStream.close();

    // read from a text archive
    std::unique_ptr<Point> pointRead;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    std::cout << pointRead->x << " " << pointRead->y << " " << pointRead->z << std::endl;

}

void NullUniquePointer()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Point> p;

    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
    outputArchive << p;
    outputStream.close();

    // read from a text archive
    std::unique_ptr<Point> pointRead;
    std::ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
    inputArchive >> pointRead;

    if(pointRead != nullptr) {
        std::cout << pointRead->x << " " << pointRead->y << " " << pointRead->z << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Pointer is null!" << std::endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    ValidUniquePointer();
    NullUniquePointer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I try that but I have this error: `class std::unique_ptr<snn::internal::Layer>’ has no member named ‘serialize’`

Answer (score 8):

as mentioned by [pmr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105672/pmr), I managed to come up the following solution, and at the first glance, everything works. In hope that someone could find it useful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
namespace boost { 
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive, class T>
inline void save(
    Archive & ar,
    const std::unique_ptr< T > &t,
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/
){
    // only the raw pointer has to be saved
    const T * const base_pointer = t.get();
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(base_pointer);
}
template<class Archive, class T>
inline void load(
    Archive & ar,
    std::unique_ptr< T > &t,
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/
){
    T *base_pointer;
    ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(base_pointer);
    t.reset(base_pointer);
}
template<class Archive, class T>
inline void serialize(
    Archive & ar,
    std::unique_ptr< T > &t,
    const unsigned int file_version
){
    boost::serialization::split_free(ar, t, file_version);
}
} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost

class MyDegrees
{
public:
  void setDeg(int d){deg = d;}
  int getDeg()const {return deg;}
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    { ar & deg; }
  int deg;
};
class gps_position
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    { ar & degrees;  }
    std::unique_ptr<MyDegrees> degrees;
public:
    gps_position(): degrees(std::unique_ptr<MyDegrees>(new MyDegrees)){};
    void setDeg(int d){degrees->setDeg(d);}
    int getDeg() const {return degrees->getDeg();}
};
int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    gps_position g;
    g.setDeg(45);
    std::cout<<g.getDeg()<<std::endl;
    { boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs); oa << g; }
    gps_position newg;
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> newg;
        std::cout<<newg.getDeg()<<std::endl;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

recent versions of boost serialization provide support for all std smart pointer types.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10325184)

Comment: @dev-null It looks like this is an answer to the question, however it would be helpful if instead of the vague "recent versions" was instead the exact version? Anything newer than "Boost 1.32"?

Comment: @RobertRamey Which version of Boost introduced this?

Comment: Nevertheless, it's valuable info. That way people don't need to try to write their own code, just c/p (if possible, of course) if they're stuck with Boost serialization version which does not support std unique_ptr serialization

Comment: There is an issue on the Boost bug tracker that says support for this has been added: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7688 but it doesn't say which version. I'm using 1.58 and it doesn't seem to know how to serialize a std::unique_ptr .

Answer (score 5):

Boost now supports smart pointers you can you #include  header file for Unique_Ptr.

```
 #include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>
```