# C++ shared_ptr serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, shared-ptr

I have a class named **A** which I want to serialize it's object in another class named **B**. but I keep getting this error:

```
error: ‘class std::shared_ptr<A>’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

class **A** is:

```
class A
{
public:
  typedef shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
  string name;

  Predicate(const string &name = ""):name(name)
  {}

private:
  template<typename Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned int v) 
  {
    archive & name;
  }
  friend class B;
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
}
```

And class **B**:

```
class B
{
public:
  typedef unordered_set<A::Ptr, 
                        APtrKeyHash, 
                        APtrKeyEq> A_set_t;
  A_set_t test;

private:
  template<typename Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned int v) 
  {
    archive & test;
  }
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
}
```

note that by shared_ptr here I mean std::shared_ptr, not boost::shared_ptr. in fact I used this line: ***using namespace std;*** before my A  class

Comment: Looks to m like the boost serialization classes don't support serializing a std::shared_ptr.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have no clue how people reach this kind of conclusion (and it gets so many upvotes too). The reason people ask on [SO] is to get informed answers from experienced users.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115220/how-can-boostserialization-be-used-with-stdshared-ptr-from-c11

Comment: @ChristianHackl I have already tried that solution as sehe answered here but it didn't work!

Comment: @ChristianHackl the version thing was my problem.thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably forgot to include

```
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

Comment: I have already tried adding this line to my code but it didn't work!

Comment: The problem was with boost version which was not updated.Thanks any way for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of shared_ptr.hpp and boost version 1.56